# Elasticsearch: Filter based on a property that is only defined on one of two mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes, `pages` and `events` that are both being searched using a simple search query:

#### Example Query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "siteHandle": "testing"
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Test New Event",
            "fields": [
              "Name^3",
              "evName^3",
              "Description^2",
              "evDescription^2",
              "_all"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The mappings look something like this:

#### `events`:

```json
{
  "events": {
    "properties": {
      "evDescription": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "evName": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "siteHandle": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "startTime": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### `pages`:

```json
{
  "pages": {
    "properties": {
      "cName": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "cPath": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "siteHandle": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I need to filter out events that have `startTime` less than now, but I'm not sure how to do it without filtering out all `pages`.

**Q: How can I search both `events` and `pages` with this query while filtering out ONLY `events` that have a `startTime` less than now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another clause to say "startTime field is missing OR startTime less than now".

[There is no **missing** query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query), so you use a combination of the bool query **must_not** and the **exists** query. It should look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": { ... }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": { ... }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "startTime"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "startTime": {
                    "lt": "now"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked after tweaking `"lt": "now"` to be `"gte": 0000000000` where 0's are a timestamp.